# Angularjs $http GET results in Undefined response when placed in Server but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, http-get

I am try to fill a dropdown selection with a list of JSON options. My JSON file is stored locally. I used Angularjs $Http GET to get the list in Dropdown, While working with localhost it was working fine, but when i host the same code in server it is not working, I dont get any errors in console. Verified for Cross origin issues also.(No problem with Cross origin).

Comment: Are you able to get this JSON content of the file with a browser by using full URL?

Comment: @nerezo i get Null if i check with service path, but i get content in localhost path